# В чём отличие списка от массива?

Tags: perl, структуры-данных

Какие ключевые особенности у этих двух конструкций (массив и список) в Perl?

Comment: Ну вот тут http://dklab.ru/chicken/nablas/20.html вроде неплохо написано. Как бы оно само собой разумеющееся, а словами выразить не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Что такое список в Perl?

Для начала вспомним, что в Perl имеется лишь **три** встроенных типа данных: 1) скаляр; 2) массив скаляров; и 3) ассоциативный массив скаляров (хэш).

**Список** (значения списка) в эту компанию не входит, так как он не является типом данных, а является конструкцией - набором значений каких-то данных (элементов), разделённых запятыми `,` и окружённый скобками `(` и `)`, когда это требует приоритет.

#### Присваивание списка элементу какого-либо типа данных из Perl

Например, в выражении: `@a = (1,3,5);`, `@a` - является **массивом**, а `(1,3,5)` - **списком** значений трёх элементов.

Но если же присвоить этот же список `(1,3,5)` в **скалярном контексте** переменной `$a`, то ей присвоиться значение последнего его элемента, т.е. `5`. `$a = (1,3,5); # $a = 5`

Список так же можно присвоить хэшу для его инициализации: `%a = ("one", 1, "two", 2);`

Вместо запятой можно использовать оператор `=>`, который рассматривает левый его операнд как строку (имя простого идентификатора - ключа):

```
%a = (one => 1, two => 2);
```

Если какой-либо ключ появиться в списке для инициализации хэша более одного раза, то победит последний объявленный.

```
%a = (one => 1, two => 2, one => 10); # будет (one => 10, two = 2)
```

#### Вычисление списка

Списки автоматически вычисляют свои элементы в контексте списка как **подсписки**.

```
((3,4), (5,98), 9) => (3,4,5,98,9)
```

Вычисление нулевых списков(подсписков) даёт всё тот же один пустой список, т.е:

```
((), (()), ()) => ()
```

Списки могут оканчиваться запятой: `(3,4,) => (3,4)`

При вычислении списка запятая рассматривается либо как разделитель элементов списка, либо как временный элемент списка:

```
(3,,8) рассматривается как ((3,),(8)) => (3,8)
(3,,,8) рассматривается как ((3,),(,),(8)) => (3,8)
```

#### Доступ к элементам списка

Значения списка можно получить по его индексу, так же, как и значение обычного массива: `(3,4,5)[1] => 4`

#### Присваивание элементам самого списка

Элементам списка можно присваивать значения:

```
($a, $b) = (8, 9); 
($a, undef, $b) = (8, 10, 9);
```

Заметка: используя данную возможность списков в Perl, можно произвести обмен значениями без использования временной переменной: `($a, $b) = ($b, $a)`.

Присваивание списка в скалярном контексте возвратит количество элементов, расположенных справа от присваивания в списке.

```
$x = (($a,$b) = (8,9,0,2));       # $x = 4, не 2
$x = (($a,$b) = foo());           # $x = количество элементов, возвращённых foo.
```

Использую данную особенность можно подсчитать количество найденных элементов в регулярном выражении:

```
$words_count = () = $string =~ /\w+/g;
```

В скалярном же контексте данное выражение возвратит ИСТИНУ или ЛОЖЬ:

```
$words_exists = $string =~ /\w+/g;
```

Если поместить хэш или массив в конец списка, то при присваивании значений списку, данных хэш или массив поглотит все остальные аргументы:

```
my ($a, $b, %rest, $c) = @_; # в $c ничего не будет
```

#### Присваивание массива скаляру

Из особенностей же массивов, можно указать поведение при присваивания целого массива какой-либо переменной. В данном случае она будет содержать количество элементов данного массива:

```
@arr = (0, 3, 4);
$arr_count = @arr; # $arr_count = 3
```

---

Написано на основе документации [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#List-value-constructors).

Comment: А вы на свой вопрос так и не ответили :) вы не показали отличия списка от массивов. большинство написанного выше справедливо и для массивов :)

Comment: Например не ясно зачем заострять внимание на присваивание списка хешу, если присваивание массива хешу даст тот же результат, нечетные элементы станут ключами, четные - значениями

Comment: @Mike массив - тип, список - набор. А дальше уже описание, что с этим можно делать. Чем не отличие? Так, конечно, большинство написанного для списков подходит и для массивов, где можно это было указано.

Comment: @Mike по поводу присваивания списка хэшу, там специального заострения внимания не было, просто показано, что произойдёт, если присвоить список к каждому элементу из трёх типов данных: скаляр, массив, хэш.

Comment: @Mike ни слова не выдрал из той статьи, а источник для ответа добавил в ответ.