# Можно ли заставить массив восприниматься как список?

Tags: perl

В данном [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/531893/199733) про списки и массивы, описывалось про то, что если присвоить список скаляру, то скаляру присвоится **последний элемент** списка, а если этому же скаляру присвоить массив, то уже скаляру присвоится **количество элементов** массива.

Отсюда вопрос: можно ли в Perl заставить массив восприниматься как список при присваивании скаляру? Т.е. что-то вместо вот этого:

```
perl -E '@a = (3,9); $b = @a; say $b'
2
```

можно было бы написать к примеру так:

```
perl -E '@a = (3,9); $b = (@a); say $b'
9 # и $b содержал бы последний элемент @a
```

Comment: А `perl -E '@a = (3,9); $b=$a[$#a]; say $b'` чем не нравится. Вряд ли вы получите последний элемент как в списке, только явно

Comment: @Mike ну можно так же и через `pop @a` и через `$a[-1]`, а так вопрос исследовательский, мало ли.

Comment: Любопытно вообще то. В списковом контексте содержимое массива отлично разворачивается в список. `@b=(0,@a,8)` содержит `0,3,9,8`, при том что в скалярном мы получаем список внутри которого содержится количество элементов, т.е. скалярный контекст был применен последовательно ко всем элементам

Comment: `my $c = ( 3,(9) );` - вот тут в `$c` будет 9.

Comment: То есть опечатка,вот тут: `my $c = (0,@a);`

Comment: @PinkTux Одна проблемка, в `my $c = (0,(@a));` $c равен 2, потому что элементы списка вычисляются в скалярном контексте. Проверяйте, что делает код перед тем как написать. https://ideone.com/Iz4vP6 без скобок то же самое

Comment: да, что-то сглючил :)

Comment: На SO уже задавали этот вопрос: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34688790/1186729

Comment: @dionys точно, срезы это могут. Оформите Ваш комментарий в качестве ответа со ссылкой на источник, отмечу его как верный.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685788/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать из массива список можно с помощью среза. И, соответственно, присваивание будет выглядеть так:

```
$b = @a[0 .. $#a];
```

или

```
$b = splice(@a);
```

Оригинал ответа: [stackoverflow.com/a/34688790/1186729](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34688790/1186729).